# Como fazer o malloc funcionar no WebAssembly sem o `emscripten_notify_memory_growth` no EMCC?

Tags: c, golang, webassembly

Estou portando um código para várias linguagens, e uma delas é o C. Eu havia feito alguns testes e funcionou, porém, em algo mais complexo, ele falha em algo bem simples: o `malloc`.

---

O código minimo para reproduzir este problema é:

```
# include "stdint.h"
# include "stdlib.h"
# include "stdio.h"

uint8_t *InputMemory;
uint8_t *OutputMemory;

int main() {
    OutputMemory = (uint8_t *) malloc(8000000);
    InputMemory = (uint8_t *) malloc(8000000);

    if (InputMemory == NULL || OutputMemory == NULL) {
        printf("Erro");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("Okay");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Estou usando o `emcc` para compilar:

```
emcc c/main.c -o testdata/wasi/c.wasm -O3
```

O WebAssembly via Wasmer aponta que o `malloc` não funcionou:

```
$ wasmer wasm.wasm
Erro
```

---

Descobri que existe o `-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH`, mas isso requer funções importadas, o que causa problemas. Então compilando usando:

```
emcc wasm.c -o wasm.wasm -O3 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH
```

Executando:

```
$ wasmer wasm.wasm
error: failed to run `wasm.wasm`
╰─▶ 1: Error while importing "wasi_snapshot_preview1"."proc_exit": unknown import. Expected Function(FunctionType { params: [I32], results: [] })
```

O `-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH` permite que o `malloc` funcione, mas ele exige um import (que é uma função definida pelo host, e então chamada pelo wasm). Esta função não está definida por padrão, e não faz parte do WASI.

---

Apenas para provar que realmente o problema é do import. Eu consegui resolver o problema, definindo um export desta funação, manualmente. Neste caso usando Wazero:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "testing"

    "github.com/tetratelabs/wazero"
    "github.com/tetratelabs/wazero/api"
    "github.com/tetratelabs/wazero/wasi"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

func TestEmscripten(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    host := wazero.NewRuntimeWithConfig(wazero.NewRuntimeConfigCompiler().WithWasmCore2())
    wasi, _ := wasi.InstantiateSnapshotPreview1(ctx, host)

    // -----------  Definindo o env (o ABI do Emscripten):
    env, _ := host.NewModuleBuilder("env").
        ExportFunction("emscripten_notify_memory_growth", func(_ int32) {}).
        Instantiate(ctx)
    // --------------------------------

    file, _ := os.ReadFile("C:\\caminho\\para\\o\\wasm")

    compiled, _ := host.CompileModule(ctx, file, wazero.NewCompileConfig())

    output := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    r, w := io.Pipe()
    go func() { io.Copy(os.Stdout, io.TeeReader(r, output)) }()

    config := wazero.NewModuleConfig().WithStdout(w).WithStderr(w).WithStartFunctions("_start")
    guest, _ := host.InstantiateModule(ctx, compiled, config)

    if !strings.Contains(output.String(), "Okay") {
        t.Error("wasm error")
    }

    for _, v := range []api.Closer{guest, env, wasi, host} {
        v.Close(ctx)
    }
}
```

Isso então retorna:

```
=== RUN   TestEmscripten
Okay--- PASS: TestEmscripten (0.03s)
PASS
```

**O WASM agora é executado sem erros**, mas isso requer que eu tenha esse import, ou ele falha, como fazer o `malloc` funcionar no WASI, sem exigir que eu implemente a função?

Ou seja:

**Como posso, no C, continuar usando `malloc` sem que ele cause o import do `emscripten_notify_memory_growth`?**

Comment: Compilei usando o GCC e não está dando nenhum problema para mim. Não entendi as conversões que você está fazendo, você está tentando guardar o ponteiro como um `unsigned`?

Comment: @BernardoLansing O problema é com o emscripten/emcc. Ele compila, mas ao executar exige o import de `emscripten_notify_memory_growth`. Essa função é chamada sempre que o `grow` é chamado, e tem o objetivo de, no Javascript, servir para atualizar o ArrayBufferView. O problema é que não estou no JS, e não queria ter que definir uma função inutil. Se eu não prover o `emscripten_notify_memory_growth`, ele falha "durante a execução" (durante o parser do WASM). A documentação diz sobre esse import, mas não diz como evita-la: https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#abi-functions

Comment: @BernardoLansing alterei o código em C, para simplicar o exemplo, e se manter ainda parecido como o código que utilizo. _Mas, de fato, o código anterior apenas converte o uintptr para uint32, já que WASM é 32bits_. Adicionei mais detalhes de como executo, e como defino os imports (e como definindo, ele resolve o problema) e como compilei (apesar de antes também está indicado). A questão é, simplesmente, como não ter que definir este import, não faz sentido ter que declarar uma função exportada para executar.